# What is the purpose of schema.json in angular 2? Why we provide it in angular-cli.json file?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0

I have found following line in angular-cli.json.

```
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json"
```

I cannot understand what is the purpose of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tells you the expected shape and validation applied to the configuration json.  Some IDEs (such as VSCode) can use it to help with autocompletion and validation while editing, but either way you can get a sense of valid keys and values.  Some serializers could also use it to validate the input against the schema automatically as well.

You can see the schema here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json, the descriptions in particular are helpful for understanding how the config is used.

Comment: Your answer is great that helps to clearly understand about this.